# How to extract separate bytes from a wav file?

Tags: java

How to extract separate bytes from a wav file and do some action. For example, print an "a"  `n` times. `n` being equal to the number of bytes?

Answer (score 3):

For file operations, you can use [`java.io`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) and/or [`java.nio`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) classes (for instance, `java.io.FileInputStream`). Either of those will give you the ability to read the bytes of any file (not just .wav files). And of course, if you want to, you can use `System.out.print` to output the letter "a" for each byte (although you don't really need to *read* the bytes to do that, just get the file length via [`java.io.File#length`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length())).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this was not exactly what I was looking for...actually..we have a wav file and say it is of 77 kb. Now what we want is to extarct the individual bytes from this file using java code.

Comment: @joydeep are you looking for the actual code of the solution (i.e. someone to do your work, unpaid)?  Or are you looking for a hint?  In the latter case, TJ's answer is very good, and tells you exactly which class to use, based on the details you have thus far provided.